# "There is no data available for the row or column" Error when trying to recover last id inserted on table on vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ado.net

i having this issue on a function that recovers the last inserted id on a table to make some else insertions where i need it.

this is my function code:

```
Public Function BuscarUltimoidOrdenProd() As Integer

        CONECTOR.Open()
        Dim SQL As String = ("SELECT MAX(idOrdenProd) as idOrdenProd FROM ordenproduccion")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, CONECTOR)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim x As Integer = Val(dr("idOrdenProd").ToString)

        Return x

        CONECTOR.Close()
    End Function
```

These are the connection variables from the class:

```
Dim CONECTOR As New OleDbConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-DNN8GME\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DB_Calcita;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")

    Dim COMANDO As New OleDbCommand
    Dim ADAPTADOR As New OleDbDataAdapter(COMANDO)
```

I dont see the error while i execute the query (SELECT MAX(idOrdenProd) as idOrdenProd FROM ordenproduccion) on SQL Managment Studio it retrieves the correct value.

This is the code from where i call the function :

```
 Public Sub GenerarOrdenStockProd(idStockMP As Integer, idStockP As Integer, CantidadProducto As Decimal, CantidadMPrima As Decimal)
        Dim FILA As DataRow = TABLA.NewRow
        Dim objOrdProd As New OrdenProduccion
        Dim x As Integer = objOrdProd.BuscarUltimoidOrdenProd
        FILA("idStockMP") = idStockMP
        FILA("idStockP") = idStockP
        FILA("CantidadProducto") = CantidadProducto
        FILA("CantidadMPrima") = CantidadMPrima
        FILA("idOrdenProd") = x
        TABLA.Rows.Add(FILA)
        Actualizar()
    End Sub
```

Comment: First things first, why are you using `OleDb` for SQL Server? You should be using The dedicated `SqlClient` provider.

Comment: You need to call `dr.Read()` to move to the first record. A couple of points though, if you're only getting a single value you'd be better of using [`OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). Secondly, don't get your newly inserted id from a separate call, use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in the same batch as your insert to ensure that the id returned is relevant to the session.

Comment: Actually strike that, just seen that although you've tagged MySQL, the connection string is SQL Server, so use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause to get the inserted ID

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You don't query the table for the max ID value. You ask the database for the most recent auto-generated value. For that you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` if you do it within the same scope or you can use `@@IDENTITY`. The latter is global though, so might be an issue in multi-user environments. You can execute a separate `SELECT @@IDENTITY` statement or include a `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` statement in the same command as your `INSERT`.